# DropDownList MultiSelect

Tags: c#, mschart

I use a MultiSelect DropDownList in my project. I would like to generate a chart when the user selects values from the DropDownList. I have two Y-axis and making a MultiSelect DropDownList for this. How can I select multiple values for the chart? The user selects two values and they represent 2 Y-axis of the chart.

Comment: Show your work in here.. Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/